# What happens to a bounty question if it gets migrated?

Tags: support, questions, bounties, migration

[This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215314/sybase-central-issues-on-64-bit-windows-2008-server-r2) clearly belongs elsewhere, but the asker already put a bounty on the question.

If the question is migrated, does the rep get refunded? Does the question continue to be a bounty question on the target site if the user has enough rep? (The asker in the referenced question does not have any associated accounts, but I'm curious about what happens.)

Edit: I just tried to add my own close vote, but apparently you can't when there's an open bounty. However, a mod should still be able to close/migrate/etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct procedure would be to flag for moderator attention. If required diamond moderators can migrate the question by removing the bounty.

- Bounty is removed and refunded
- Question is closed and migrated

<sub>I have flagged the question as well for the SO mods to look at it</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Questions with bounties on them can't be closed or migrated (unless by a superpower of mod type personage).  It'll stay until the bounty's accepted or expired.

Comment: +1, I didn't know bounty questions cannot be migrate to somewhere else.

Comment: @Mark: Migration is simply one form of closing.

Comment: Ever diamond moderators **cannot** close or migrate questions with bounties.  However, diamond moderators can remove the bounty and then close or migrate the question.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that if the question is migrated and the bounty was not awarded in the original page, then the reputation is refunded. I proposed +100 bounty for this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/a-sequence-of-order-statistics-from-an-iid-sequence) in stats.SE which I could not award, so I suggested to migrate the question, and then proposed +100 bounty in math.SE. For other reasons I checked my `/reputation` page today and saw that I had 100 more reputation than I should. So the reputation is refunded, but with some time delay, about a month in my case.